# Why is my ArrayList of String[]'s not sorting properly?

Tags: java, arraylist, selection-sort

I am reading data in from a file, and asking the user which category they would like to sort by. The file has 13 columns (starting with country, year, and continent, then a list of double statistics that I am ignoring for the time being) and 792 rows. I have had no trouble initializing the ArrayList<String[]>, and I have a method to print out the rows and they are formatted correctly.

I am trying to sort the ArrayList based on one of the columns (I am using the first column right now as comparing the Country names is the easiest to see, and the original file is already organized by year, so that would not be a good way to tell if the sorting worked). I currently am trying to implement a selectionSort method which appears to work alright, but when I print out the rows of the modified ArrayList, there are several rows that are out of order (but it appears that many sections have been better organized).

Here are a few lines from the file for reference when converted to a String[]:

[ Singapore 2015 AS 6.572000027 1.69227767 1.353814363 0.949492395 0.549840569 0.345965981 0.464307785 85 ]

[ Netherlands 2015 EU 7.376999855 1.503944635 1.428939223 0.810696125 0.585384488 0.47048983 0.282661825 84 ]

[ Canada 2015 NA 7.315999985 1.479204416 1.481348991 0.834557652 0.611100912 0.435539722 0.287371516 83 ]

Here is the chunk of code for the selectionSort method that I am having an issue with.
ArrayList<String[]> data is the data being read in, and int sortIndex for the Country example is zero, the column of each individual String[] that I am trying to compare.

```
public static void selectionSort(ArrayList<String[]> data, int sortIndex){
    int i;
    int j;
    String[] temp;
    int indexSmallest = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < data.size()-1; i++) {
        indexSmallest = i;
            
        for (j= i + 1; j < data.size(); j++) {
            if (data.get(j)[sortIndex].compareTo(data.get(i)[sortIndex]) < 0) {
                indexSmallest = j;
            }
        }
        temp = data.get(i);
        data.set(i, data.get(indexSmallest));
        data.set(indexSmallest, temp);
    }
}
```

I am new to stack overflow, so if there is any additional information I should include, please let me know! I have read through a couple similar questions but have not been able to figure out what is wrong with my process. Thanks in advance!

Update:
Here is my initialization of the ArrayList, called dataAL in my main method:

```
while (currLine != null) {
    dataAL.add(currLine.split("\\,", -1));
    lineNum++;
    currLine = readBuffer.readLine();
}
```

I output the arrays with a separate printRow(String[] row) method which simply prints each row passed to the method separated by spaces and with hard brackets on each end (as seen in the example rows I listed above). The ArrayList<String[]> is called dataAL, but when passed to the sort method it is named data, which is then passed to the insertion sort method as data again. Here is the printing of the data:

```
for (int k = 0; k < data.size(); k++){
    printRow(data.get(k));
}
```

I am expecting that as the rows print out, the rows are organized alphabetically by index 0 of each String[], which is the country names that I am comparing, and while some sections are in alphabetical order, the entire list is not.

Comment: Please provide the code that initialises your array with sample data, and where the call is made to your sort function, and the result is output. Explain how the output is not how you expected it.

Comment: @trincot I have updated my post based on your question request

Comment: We should be able to run the code and reproduce the issue. Please provide a runnable example. Realise that community members usually don't have the patience to piece things together, create an input file, fill in the missing pieces and hopefully get something running and see the problem occurring.

Comment: Will the problem occur with the example data you've shown us? If not, are you able to show a small example of data where the problem does occur?

Comment: By the way, have you stepped through the code with a debugger, stepping through the code while monitoring the values of variables?

Comment: your data seems not to have any comma, but code is splitting using `"\\,"` (escaping is not needed for comma AFAIK) - always best to post a [mre] and an example of which data is not being sorted correctly, including the wrong result... (at least posted data, assuming correctly split, is being correctly sorted IMHO)

Comment: @user85421 the output was readable, however the AL was not organized in alphabetical order by country like I had intended. I ran a smaller example and it worked just fine, however. I am currently working with the solution provided by Eritrean, but will likely still go back and try to fix the Selection Sort method. I now believe there may be something I am missing with the more complex data that I am using, some detail that I am missing.

Comment: I, like @user85421, was suspecting the problem might be in the data, not your code. But, you got an answer that showed how to use Java's `List#sort` method, and the error did not occur. That is evidence the problem is with your code, not the data. Although the answer fixes the sort, it doesn't explain where is the original problem. I hope you will continue to explore this problem.

Comment: Off-topic: By the way, if you find out why the cities are not being sorted properly, and you fix that, there is future other problem: Comparing numeric values represented by `String` only works if all the values have the same number of digits to the left of the decimal point. That would be the same number of digits for integers.

Comment: What happens if you refactor `data` to be an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't complicate things unnecessarily. You can use the sort method of `List`, which accepts a comparator:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add(new String[] {"Singapore", "2015", "AS", "6.572000027", "1.69227767", "1.353814363", "0.949492395",
                             "0.549840569", "0.345965981", "0.464307785", "85"});
    myList.add(new String[] {"Netherlands", "2015", "EU", "7.376999855", "1.503944635", "1.428939223", "0.810696125",
                          "0.585384488", "0.47048983", "0.282661825", "84"});
    myList.add(new String[] {"Canada", "2015", "NA", "7.315999985", "1.479204416", "1.481348991", "0.834557652",
                             "0.611100912", "0.435539722", "0.287371516", "83"});

    System.out.println("Before sorting");
    myList.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
    
    sortByIndex(myList, 0);

    System.out.println("After sorting");
    myList.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
}

public static void sortByIndex(List<String[]> data, int sortIndex) {
    data.sort(Comparator.comparing(d -> d[sortIndex]));
}
```

Of course, you may have to check beforehand whether the index is valid.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Although I am not sure what issue I had with my code, this is a great and much simpler solution. I will have to read on this Comparator object and the notation used as I am not familiar, but thank you much for your help!

Comment: That being said, the target of this assignment is to practice and demonstrate an understanding of searching and sorting algorithms, and this is the part focused on the sorting, hence the use of the Selection Sort method. I will likely go back and try to figure out the issue I had, but I have found out that it works for a smaller, simpler ArrayList<String[]>, so I will have to look more carefully into the data I am using.

Answer (score 2):

> *"... I am reading data in from a file, and asking the user which category they would like to sort by. The file has 13 columns (starting with country, year, and continent, then a list of double statistics ..."*

A simple solution here is to utilize a *[class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)*, to contain each entry.

Here is an example.

```java
class Entry {
    String country, continent;
    int year, h;
    double a, b, c, d, e, f, g;

    static Entry parse(String s) {
        Entry e = new Entry();
        String[] a = s.split(" ");
        e.country = a[0];
        e.year = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
        e.continent = a[2];
        e.a = Double.parseDouble(a[3]);
        e.b = Double.parseDouble(a[4]);
        e.c = Double.parseDouble(a[5]);
        e.d = Double.parseDouble(a[6]);
        e.e = Double.parseDouble(a[7]);
        e.f = Double.parseDouble(a[8]);
        e.g = Double.parseDouble(a[9]);
        e.h = Integer.parseInt(a[10]);
        return e;
    }
}
```

This will make parsing, slightly more stream-lined.

```java
String s
    = "Singapore 2015 AS 6.572000027 1.69227767 1.353814363 0.949492395 0.549840569 0.345965981 0.464307785 85\n"
    + "Netherlands 2015 EU 7.376999855 1.503944635 1.428939223 0.810696125 0.585384488 0.47048983 0.282661825 84\n"
    + "Canada 2015 NA 7.315999985 1.479204416 1.481348991 0.834557652 0.611100912 0.435539722 0.287371516 83";
List<Entry> l = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner t = new Scanner(s)) {
    while (t.hasNext()) l.add(Entry.parse(t.nextLine()));
}
```

And, from here you can utilize the *[List#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator))* method, to compare a specific *[field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)*, of *Entry*; permitting it is *"comparable"*.

```java
l.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.country));
```

```
[{'Canada', 2015, 'NA', ... }, {'Netherlands', 2015, 'EU', ... }, {'Singapore', 2015, 'AS', ... }]
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured I would update the post with an answer, as I found the mistake when working on a different project. Here is the code that I had typed for iterating through the ArrayList<String[]> to sort:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.size()-1; i++) {
    indexSmallest = i;
        
    for (j= i + 1; j < data.size(); j++) {
        if (data.get(j)[sortIndex].compareTo(data.get(i)[sortIndex]) < 0) {
            indexSmallest = j;
        }
    }
    temp = data.get(i);
    data.set(i, data.get(indexSmallest));
    data.set(indexSmallest, temp);
}
```

In the condition, I should have been comparing data.get(j)[sortIndex] with data.get(indexSmallest)[sortIndex], not data.get(i)[sortIndex]. It is one of those things that once I caught it, it fell so obvious. Here is the collect chunk of code I should have used:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.size()-1; i++) {
    indexSmallest = i;
        
    for (j= i + 1; j < data.size(); j++) {
        if (data.get(j)[sortIndex].compareTo(data.get(indexSmallest)[sortIndex]) < 0) {
            indexSmallest = j;
        }
    }
    temp = data.get(i);
    data.set(i, data.get(indexSmallest));
    data.set(indexSmallest, temp);
}
```

I appreciate all of the insight, suggestions and debugging strategies provided by you all.